# Qt5 near equivalent of GTK3 GtkPaned

Tags: linux, qt, qt5, gtk3

For the [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) project (a GPLv3+ project on [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/bstarynk/refpersys/), now at [commit `57c51b8b1bd19feb27de`](https://gitlab.com/bstarynk/refpersys/commit/57c51b8b1bd19feb27deae11edd1dbe1f3c6b039)) I need a near equivalent (in look and feel) in Qt5 of GTK3 [GtkPaned](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkPaned.html), that is an area with two subareas whose separation can be "slided" by the user.

I am pretty certain to have used on Linux some KDE applications (or plain Qt ones) having such a thing and look and feel. For example the [Kate editor](https://kate-editor.org/) has a *View -> Split View* menu.

I cannot find in Qt5 documentation its equivalent. [QMdiArea](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmdiarea.html) seems too general, or I am using it wrongly in files [window_qrps.cc](https://gitlab.com/bstarynk/refpersys/-/blob/master/window_qrps.cc) and [qthead_qrps.hh](https://gitlab.com/bstarynk/refpersys/-/blob/master/qthead_qrps.hh) of RefPerSys.

Comment: [QSplitter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplitter.html#details)

Comment: Please make that answer! Thanks